# Making text a hyperlink on a Facebook timeline post

Tags: facebook

How can I make text I enter into my Facebook timeline a hyperlink?  For example, I want write

```
                          Checkout my new site.
```

and have "site" link to `www.mynewsite.com` when clicked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried what you said, but go through the below mentioned document, it might help you.

[FB LINK DOC](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=367068750846)

Thanks

Comment: The linked text refers to hyperlinks in blog posts, but what is the mechanism to include hyperlinks in Facebook posts? There is no "chain link icon?!